# How to create a full length video from images with FFmpeg?

Tags: image, ffmpeg

I have more than a thousand images that I want to transform into a 3 minutes video. I tried using this line `ffmpeg -r 30 -i "E:/White-box-Cartoonization/test_code/cartoonized_images/$flower%03d.bmp" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4` it worked but creates only a 5 seconds video. What do I need to do to turn it into a full length 3 minutes video?

Answer (score 2):

If you have 1250 images and want an output duration of 180 seconds:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1250/180 -i input%03d.bmp -c:v libx264 -vf format=yuv420p output.mp4
```

This example results in a frame rate of 6.94. Some players can't handle such low frame rates. If your player does not like it then add the `-r` output option to make a normal output frame rate. ffmpeg will duplicate the frames but the output will look the same.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1250/180 -i input%03d.bmp -c:v libx264 -vf format=yuv420p -r 25 output.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

For 3 minutes of video at 30 frames per second (`-r` parameter) you'd need `30*60*3` images: 5400 images.

Your source parameter specifies there would be only 3 digits, so you have a maximum of 1000 source images:

```
$flower%03d.bmp => $flower000.bmp .. $flower999.bmp
```

1000 images at 30 frames per second should give about 30 seconds of video ... if you actually have `$flowerxxx.bmp` files.

You might need a 4th digit in there somewhere.

```
$flower%04d.bmp
```